# GeoTiff - how to slice into 0.1 x 0.1 degree images

Tags: java, geolocation, slice, tiff, geotiff

I am working on slicing GeoTiff (BigTiff) with resolution of 58808x30323 into 0.1 degree to 0.1 degree pieces, so we will be able to send pieces to the mobile devices. I am implementing converter in Java. The image represents DEM - Ditigal elavation model (10 meter)

**What I have and what I know:**

- the image is divided into 128x128 tiles
- I have successfully implemented reading IFD (image file directory) values and I can read each tile and decompress it (the LZW decompression is used)

**Problems and questions:**

- I do not understand how to connect image size, number of tiles inside image and geoLocation data provided in the file. I have read that Geolocation data is related to the top upper pixel of the image. Can someone explain me that - what formula to use? (Would bilinear interpolation solve the problem when I uderstand connection between pixels and coordinates?)
- The image is separated into 128x128 tiles. What's the unit of 128x128 tiles? I suspect that pixels are not the case, because 58808(image width) or 30323(image height) is simply not dividable with 128. How to figure out how many tiles goes into 1 row?

**Image meta data:**

```
FileSize 3249 MB
FileType BTF
FileTypeExtension btf
MIMEType mage/x-tiff-bigMIMEType
ImageWidth 58808
ImageHeight 30323
BitsPerSample 32
Compression LZW
PhotometricInterpretation BlackIsZero
SamplesPerPixel 1
PlanarConfiguration Chunky
Predictor None
TileWidth 128
TileLength 128
SampleFormat Float
PixelScale 10 10 0
ModelTiePoint 0 0 0 106549.267203769 576922.512073626 0
TileOffsets // there is 109020 offset numbers
TileByteCounts // there is 109020 byteCount numbers
GeoTiffDirectory
    1 1 0 20 // Header
    1024 0 1 1  // ModelTypeProjected   -> 1   /* Projection Coordinate System         */
    1025 0 1 1  // RasterPixelIsPoint -> 2
    1026 34737 31 0  // GTCitationGeoKey
    2048 0 1 32767  // GeographicTypeGeoKey  
    2049 34737 63 31  // GeogCitationGeoKey 
    2050 0 1 6312 // Geodetic Datum Codes -> Datum_Militar_Geographische_Institut
    2054 0 1 9102 // -> Angular_Degree =    9102
    2057 34736 1 7 // GeogLinearUnits  
    2059 34736 1 6 // GeogInvFlatteningGeoKey
    2061 34736 1 8 // GeogPrimeMeridianLongGeoKey
    3072 0 1 32767 // ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey -> User defined
    3074 0 1 32767 // ProjectionGeoKey -> User defined
    3075 0 1 8  // ProjCoordTransGeoKey -> CT_LambertConfConic_2SP
    3076 0 1 9001 // ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey -> Linear meter
    3078 34736 1 2  // ProjStdParallel1GeoKey         = 3078  /* GeogAngularUnit */
    3079 34736 1 3  // ProjStdParallel2GeoKey         = 3079  /* GeogAngularUnit */
    3084 34736 1 1  // ProjFalseOriginLongGeoKey      = 3084  /* GeogAngularUnit */
    3085 34736 1 0  // ProjFalseOriginLatGeoKey       = 3085  /* GeogAngularUnit */
    3086 34736 1 4  // ProjFalseOriginEastingGeoKey   = 3086  /* ProjLinearUnits */
    3087 34736 1 5  //ProjFalseOriginNorthingGeoKey  = 3087  /* ProjLinearUnits */
    0 0 0 0II // End
GeoTiffDoubleParams 47.5 13.3333333333333 46 49 400000 400000 299.1528128 6377397.155 0II
GeoTiffAsciiParams PCS Name = MGI_Austria_Lambert|GCS Name = GCS_MGI|Ellipsoid = Bessel_1841|Primem = Greenwich||
GDALNoData -3.4028230607370965e+038
ImageSize 58808x30323
Megapixels 1783.2
```

**The tiff file also has tfw file:**

```
10.0000000000
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
-10.0000000000
106554.2672037689
576917.5120736258
```

Comment: Not sure about the GEO info, but the TIFF tile situation is easy to explain. The width in tiles = (page_width + tile_width - 1) / tile_width. The same applies to the tile height. The width and height don't need to be integral numbers of tiles, because you can have partially defined tiles.

Comment: The gdal_merge uses nearest interpolation and unfortunately you can change it (ok with exception of in depth knowledge of the script and gdal library). The -overwrite option you have mentioned just allows gdal to write into the existing files.